# ubuntu 16.04 nvidia prime problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, nvidia-prime, bbswitch

I have **asus n552** with optimus (nviadi 960m and intel gpu) installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS logged in  with `nouveau.modeset=0` in grub
 and installed **nvidia 361.42** and intel microcode in additional drivers. now prime is installed but when i select intel (power saving mode) in prime and log out-in cpu fan starts with high speed and if i logout or reboot it freezes in a black screen and i have to force power it off. But with nvidia selected in prime everything is ok.

Comment: I have the same problem ,

Comment: Check my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966913/boot-with-nvidia-or-intel-driver-loaded/971304#971304 Hope it helps! :)