# Boot with nvidia or intel driver loaded

Tags: grub2, nvidia, graphics, intel, nvidia-prime

I have a problem with nvidia-prime, it doesnt work. When switch to Intel graphics and then start X server, notebook freezes. Intel graphics worked fine before I installed nvidia driver. I tried different drivers and configurations, nothing helped.

So I want to try switch graphics without prime, at the boot time. Is it possible to boot with nvidia driver disabled and intel loaded ? (Some option in grub or whatever). So I choose in grub menu with which graphics(driver) I want to boot.
Nvidia 1050, Intel i7 7700 HQ, Asus ROG Strix 553glvd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue for months and tried a lot of stuff. As soon as I switched to the Intel graphics (with prime) using the Nvidia driver I couldn't boot my laptop. My machine worked well with the Nvidia GPU but since I wanted to get longer battery life and less fan noise I wanted to use the Intel Graphics.

I solved the non-boot issue by adding a parameter to kernel. It worked for me on my Dell XPS 15 9560 for both Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 17.04.

First make sure that you've the Nvidia driver installed and running (I use 384.90)

Edit the following file:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Find this line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Replace it with:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_rev_override=1"`

After that, run the following commands:

`sudo update-grub && sudo update-grub2`

Select intel with Nvidia Prime:

`sudo prime-select intel`

Reboot and voila, it should work! :) You can double check that you're running the Intel graphics with this command:

`sudo prime-select query`

It should print 'intel' if you're using the Intel card.

Good luck!